# Number of rows/columns in table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-cli

I was experimenting with the Timeseries example in cassandra mentioned at http://planetcassandra.org/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/.
   Now how can I verify that the example in figure 2 (Partition the row depending on the weather station and date) has created only two rows and each row contains two columns?

Regards,
Seenu.

Answer (score 1):

You can query each partition key "row" and see how many "columns" are present within it (note that clustered columns in CQL are rows with a common partition key prefix, so the example is really creating what looks like four rows in CQL).

```
SELECT event_time, temperature FROM temperature_by_day WHERE weatherstation_id='1234ABCD' AND date='2013-04-03';

 event_time               | temperature
--------------------------+-------------
 2013-04-03 07:01:00-0400 |         72F
 2013-04-03 07:02:00-0400 |         73F

SELECT event_time, temperature FROM temperature_by_day WHERE weatherstation_id='1234ABCD' AND date='2013-04-04';

 event_time               | temperature
--------------------------+-------------
 2013-04-04 07:01:00-0400 |         73F
 2013-04-04 07:02:00-0400 |         74F
```

Or get all the clustered columns at once:

```
SELECT event_time, temperature FROM temperature_by_day WHERE weatherstation_id='1234ABCD' and DATE in ('2013-04-03', '2013-04-04');

 event_time               | temperature
--------------------------+-------------
 2013-04-03 07:01:00-0400 |         72F
 2013-04-03 07:02:00-0400 |         73F
 2013-04-04 07:01:00-0400 |         73F
 2013-04-04 07:02:00-0400 |         74F
```

Or just look at the contents of the entire table:

```
SELECT * from temperature_by_day ;

 weatherstation_id | date       | event_time               | temperature
-------------------+------------+--------------------------+-------------
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-04 | 2013-04-04 07:01:00-0400 |         73F
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-04 | 2013-04-04 07:02:00-0400 |         74F
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 | 2013-04-03 07:01:00-0400 |         72F
          1234ABCD | 2013-04-03 | 2013-04-03 07:02:00-0400 |         73F
```

To see how the data is stored on disk, you can flush the keyspace to disk and then run the sstable2json utility on the data file.  This will show that each partition key is stored only once, and the clustering columns are stored in sorted order within the partition key.

```
root@c1:/var/lib/cassandra/data/tkeyspace/temperature_by_day-e1a74970912211e4aa1ea3121441a41b# sstable2json tkeyspace-temperature_by_day-ka-1-Data.db
[
{"key": "1234ABCD:2013-04-04",
 "cells": [["2013-04-04 07\\:01-0400:","",1420054084914905],
           ["2013-04-04 07\\:01-0400:temperature","73F",1420054084914905],
           ["2013-04-04 07\\:02-0400:","",1420054155058044],
           ["2013-04-04 07\\:02-0400:temperature","74F",1420054155058044]]},
{"key": "1234ABCD:2013-04-03",
 "cells": [["2013-04-03 07\\:01-0400:","",1420054017282283],
           ["2013-04-03 07\\:01-0400:temperature","72F",1420054017282283],
           ["2013-04-03 07\\:02-0400:","",1420054049403031],
           ["2013-04-03 07\\:02-0400:temperature","73F",1420054049403031]]}
]
```

Comment: Since I was from an RDBMS background, the select * output in CQL confused me that 4 rows are created.  But do you think checking the nodetool cfstatus output will inform me only the column values are stored and not the partition keys for every new insert?

Comment: Hi Srinivasa, I added an example to my answer to show how the data is stored on disk.  You can see that the partition keys are not stored for every insert.  They define a data bucket into which the clustered data is placed so that it can be queried efficiently.